# Changing form fields with ajax but field values not passing on submit

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a standard form with a drop down list of customers, using ajax when a customer is selected it calls the load-customers.php page and changes the form fields entirely based on customer_id whilst filling it with the relevant information.

One of these fields is another drop drown called address_id which again allows the user to select from multiple addresses already defined for the selected customer.

The issue is, address_id is not being passed to $_POST on submit, to be fair none of the other fields are either... but the other fields are just placeholders and i only care about the customer_id and address_id.

How do i get around this? This is the only bit of ajax I've ever used.

ajax:

```
function getCustomer(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load-customers.php",
        data:'id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#customer").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

customer:

```
<div class='form-group row'>
    <label class='col-md-4 control-label'>Quick Select</label>
    <div class='col-md-8 selectContainer'>
        <div class='input-group'>
            <span class='input-group-addon'><i class=''></i></span>
            <select name='Customer_ID' class='form-control selectpicker' id='Customer_ID'
                    onChange="getCustomer(this.value);">
                <option value='0'>Please create a new Customer</option>
                <?php
                $sell_type = "Trade";
                $getcustomer = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE type = :type");
                $getcustomer->bindParam(':type', $sell_type);
                $getcustomer->execute();
                foreach ($getcustomer->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
                    $customer_id = $row['id'];
                    $customer_name = $row['name'];
                    $customer_company = $row['company'];

                    if (!empty($customer_company)) {
                        $customer = $customer_company;
                    } else {
                        $customer = $customer_companyname;
                    }
                    echo "<option value='$customer_id'>$customer</option> ";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='address'>
    // address results go here
</div>
```

address:

```
    <div class='form-group row'> 
      <label class='col-md-4 control-label'>Postcode</label>
        <div class='col-md-8 selectContainer'>
        <div class='input-group'>
            <span class='input-group-addon'><i class=''></i></span>
        <select id='address_id' class='form-control selectpicker' name='address_id' >
";

        $getaddresses = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE customer_id = :id");
        $getaddresses->bindParam(':id', $customer_id);
        $getaddresses->execute();
            foreach ($getaddresses->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
                $address_id = $row['id']; 
                $postcode = $row['postcode'];
                $areacode = $row['areacode'];

                echo "
                  <option value='$address_id'>$postcode</option>
                ";
            }

 echo "
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The form itself is quite large but the header is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal justify-content-center" action="new.php" method="post"  id="form">
```

and submitted with:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form after you change the form fields?

Comment: Show the resulting form.

Comment: But you are only passing `id`. Why do you expect to also get other fields?.  My advice to you is get a tutorial on Ajax with php.

Comment: I expected this behaviour because this builds the form correctly and all the elements have the correct information.

Comment: You need a `<form>` around the `address_id` dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I've ended up submitting the form with ajax and it seems to be doing the trick with adding the form around it too.

Comment: try to set { id:val } in data ajax